# Building failed kivy iOS with Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, macos, kivy

Compile a touchtracer project does not work. Here's my step: I enter command:

```
./toolchain.py create Touchtracer ~/code/kivy/examples/demo/touchtracer
open touchtracer-ios/touchtracer.xcodeproj
```

Here's the corresponding scipt output:

> building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/maccx/code/kivy/examples/demo/touchtracer/." failed: No such file or directory (2)
>   done
>
> sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
>   total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
>   rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
>   Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23

Setup: tutorial in kivy guide

Comment: So, fairly obvious first question: Does the directory `/Users/maccx/code/kivy/examples/demo/touchtracer/` actually exist?

Comment: I'm successful. Thanks

Comment: @Nam How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have already solved it but to help others the answer is....

./toolchain.py create

creates a package of your source code at

default path in example is  ./toolchain.py create Touchtracer ~/code/kivy/examples/demo/touchtracer

but if there is no touch tracer code at that location you will face issue.you can go to application-> kivy-> (show package content) examples search for touch tracer in demo or some place give that path or copy paste it some where and use that.

Your source code is what you work at not your package at yourapp-ios